# Install .NET Framework 3.5 on Mac through Crossover (Wine)?

Tags: windows, mac, .net-framework, emulation, crossover

I'm trying to run a piece of software ([ConnectWise PSA](http://www.connectwise.com/connectwise.php)) on my Mac without having to run [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/). I'm running Parallels now, but want to get away from it if possible.

I use [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/), a Windows emulator based on [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). ConnectWise requires .NET Framework 3.5 to run. According to CodeWeavers (CrossOver creator), it [seems like I can](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=4662) install the .NET Framework 3.5. The problem I'm running into is that in order to install .NET Framework 3.5, you have to install .NET Framework 2.0, 2.0 SP1, 3.0, 3.0 SP1 and *then* 3.5. I can't seem to get past 2.0 SP1.

I created a new WinXP bottle to test this out on and was able to install 2.0 with no issues. When it gets to the point when it's going to install 2.0 SP1, it gives this error message:

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this since I'm running a Windows **XP** emulator.

Does anyone know a workaround for installing .NET Framework in CrossOver or can anyone think of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's supported, because CodeWeavers [states otherwise](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=9322).

Furthermore, I would suggest you give Wine a try, couldn't hurt.
[Look here for more info](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10166&iTestingId=26583).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The strange thing is that .NET 2.0 SP1 is not supported, but .NET 3.5 [is supported](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/?app_id=4662). Don't you have to have 2.0 SP1 installed to install 3.5?

Comment: Apparenlty not, [see here](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/?app_id=4662;forum=1;msg=114984).  Mind you, it's still experimental and unsupported.

Comment: Also, it seem you can install it via "CrossTie", though, never tried that before.  YMMV.

Comment: Unfortunately, whoever wrote that instructional wasn't very detailed on the steps. I wasn't able to do the registry stuff, so it didn't work. Thanks for finding this for me though. I'll probably wait for CrossOver 11, which is supposed to have built in support for .NET 3.5 Thanks again.